# How to detect what page I came from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Is there any way to detect from what page you came from with Java Script?

I orriginally have added a parameter in the link

```
mywebsite.com/thispage.jsp?lastpage=lastPageName
```

But I think this is not a good way to detect it.

I want to use it to create an "404: Page not found" site with a 'go Back!' Button, so I can just link from every page and go back to this exact page.

If you know a better Idea to create this Button, you are welcome to comment it.

**Answer:**
For some reason a java method that run `history.back()` did not work for me.

```html
<a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>
```

This direct javascript usage did work for me

**EDIT:**
I ran my file in the internal browser from Eclipse, what didn't work. The moment I started testing on Chrome or a `Chromium based browser` it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a back method on the `window.history` object you can use to do that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back

Comment: This does for some reason not work for me, I also tested history.go(-1)